# Error al definir una funcion en lenguaje C (Me dice funcion no definida)

Tags: c, funcion

Escribí esta función tal cual como sale en el libro pero me sale el siguiente mensaje al compilar con GCC

"/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccM0qYIq.o: en la función `main': fig05_04.c:(.text+0x6c): referencia a` maximo' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

```
/* Figura 5.4: fig05_04.c
 * Encuentra el maximo de tres numeros enteros */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int maximo(int n1, int n2, int n3);

int main(void){

    system("clear");

    int numero1,
        numero2,
        numero3;

    printf("Introduzca tres enteros");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &numero1, &numero2, &numero3);

    printf("El maximo numero es %d.\n", maximo(numero1, numero2, numero3));

    return 0;

} /* Fin de la funcion main */

int maximmo(int n1, int n2, int n3){

    int max = n1;

    if(n2 > max){
        max = n2;
    }

    if(n3 > max){
        max = n3;
    }

    return max;

} /* Fin de la funcion maximo */
```

En realidad no se lo que ocurre ya que cree el prototipo ante de la linea donde comienza la función main y toda la estructura de la función "máximo" que esta al final la he revisado varias veces y no veo que es lo que ocurre.

No logro ver el error en el código.

Comment: El error indica que no encuentra la funcion maximo, porque escribiste maximo con dos (m), "maximmo" cambialo a "maximo" y listo

Answer (score 2):

El error que lanza es porque c no encuentra la funcion máximo, porque escribiste la funcion con dos (m). Cambiar el nombre de la funcion de "maximmo" a "maximo" y tu programa funcionará sin problemas

```c
//El error esta en el nombre de esta función, cambiar de "maximmo" a "maximo"
int maximmo(int n1, int n2, int n3){

    int max = n1;

    if(n2 > max){
        max = n2;
    }

    if(n3 > max){
        max = n3;
    }

    return max;

} /* Fin de la funcion maximo */
```

Comment: Que gafo soy, gracias.